# Matching character ranges in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

What is the equivalent of the **OCaml**:

```
match x with 
| 'a'..'k' -> 1
...
```

in **F#**?

(short of `| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' ...` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a match guard to add a condition:

```
match x with 
| t when t >= 'a' && t <= 'k' -> 1
```